# Python metaClass and import *

Tags: python

Main Goal: Automatically register classes (by a string) in a factory to be created dynamically at run time using that string, classes can be in their own file and not grouped in one file.

I have couple of classes which all inherit from the same base class and they define a string as their type.

A user wants to get an instance of one of these classes but only knows the type at run time.

Therefore I have a factory to create an instance given a type. 
I didn't want to hard code an "if then statements" so I have a meta class to register all the sub classes of the base class:

```
class MetaRegister(type):
    # we use __init__ rather than __new__ here because we want
    # to modify attributes of the class *after* they have been
    # created
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        if not hasattr(cls, 'registry'):
            # this is the base class.  Create an empty registry
            cls.registry = {}
        else:
            # this is a derived class.  Add cls to the registry
            interface_id = cls().get_model_type()
            cls.registry[interface_id] = cls

        super(MetaRegister, cls).__init__(name, bases, dct)
```

The problem is that for this to work the factory has to import all the subclass (So the meta class runs). 
To fix this you can use `from X import *`
But for this to work you need to define an `__all__` var in the `__init__.py` file of the package to include all the sub classes.

I don't want to hard code the sub classes because it beats the purpose of using the meta class.

I can go over the file in the package using:

```
import glob

from os.path import dirname, basename, isfile

modules = glob.glob(dirname(__file__) + "/*.py")
__all__ = [basename(f)[:-3] for f in modules if isfile(f)]
```

Which works great, **but** the project needs to compile to a single .so file, which nullifies the use of the file system.

So how could I achieve my main goal of creating instances at run time without hard codding the type?

Is there a way to populate an `__all__` var at run time without touching the filesystem?

In Java I'd probably decorate the class with an annotation and then get all the classes with that annotation at run time, is there something similar on python?

I know there are decorators in python but I'm not sure I can use them in this way.

Edit 1:
Each subclass must be in a file:

```
- Models
-- __init__.py
-- ModelFactory.py
-- Regression
--- __init__.py
--- Base.py
--- Subclass1.py
--- Subclass2ExtendsSubclass1.py
```

Edit 2: Some code to Illustrate the problem:

```
+ main.py
|__ Models
    |__ __init__.py
    |__ ModelFactory.py
    |__ Regression
        |__ init__.py
        |__ Base.py
        |__ SubClass.py
        |__ ModelRegister.py

main.py

from models.ModelFactory import ModelFactory

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ModelFactory()


ModelFactory.py

from models.regression.Base import registry
import models.regression

class ModelFactory(object):
    def get(self, some_type):
        return registry[some_type]


ModelRegister.py
class ModelRegister(type):
    # we use __init__ rather than __new__ here because we want
    # to modify attributes of the class *after* they have been
    # created
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        print cls.__name__
        if not hasattr(cls, 'registry'):
            # this is the base class.  Create an empty registry
            cls.registry = {}
        else:
            # this is a derived class.  Add cls to the registry
            interface_id = cls().get_model_type()
            cls.registry[interface_id] = cls

        super(ModelRegister, cls).__init__(name, bases, dct)

Base.py

from models.regression.ModelRegister import ModelRegister

class Base(object):
    __metaclass__ = ModelRegister

    def get_type(self):
        return "BASE"

SubClass.py

from models.regression.Base import Base


class SubClass(Base):
    def get_type(self):
        return "SUB_CLASS"
```

Running it you can see only "Base" it printed. 
Using a decorator gives the same results.

Comment: Very good question, I'd love to see an answer because I faced this problem many times but to my knowledge, it's not possible without resolving to hardcode classes or to glob auto imports of other classes files.

Comment: When you say that the project needs to compile to a single `.so` file, what do you mean? How are you "compiling" the project? Can you amend the compiling process to generate the `__all__` in the package's `__init__.py`?

Comment: @jme we are currently using Nuitka to compile the entire source to a single .so file. We could change the build process to recreate the `__init__.py` file but I'd like to avoid it, it's more complicated, can break easily if a package is moved or renamed and it widens the gap between a dev machine and the build machine.

Comment: I see. Ultimately the problem boils down to dynamically determining which submodules exist within the package. If you were using CPython, `pkgutil` would be the way to go. But since this is a Nuitka extension module, and it doesn't look like Nuitka provides a way to determine an extension module's submodules from within Python, auto-generating `__init__.py` looks like the simplest option. Installing the package into your dev environment, writing a script which imports the package and uses `pkgutil` to list submodules, and generating `from . import submodulename` seems relatively robust to me.

Comment: @jme I actually did try to use pkgutil but it didn't work.

Comment: Right, it shouldn't work on a compiled extension module, but if you install the package as a normal Python package (before compiling) then `pkgutil`'s `iter_modules` should work. So the idea would be to write a quick script which installs the pure-Python package into, say, a virtualenv, imports it, inspects it via `pkgutil`, then spits out a generated `__init__.py`. I'll demonstrate what I mean by editing my answer.

Comment: On second thought, installing the package into a venv isn't really necessary -- we can just read the names of the submodules from the filesystem to generate `__init__.py`. The example has been added to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

A simple way to register classes as runtime is to use decorators:

```
registry = {}

def register(cls):
    registry[cls.__name__] = cls
    return cls

@register
class Foo(object):
    pass

@register
class Bar(object):
    pass
```

This will work if all of your classes are defined in the same module, and if that module is imported at runtime. Your situation, however, complicates things. First, you want to define your classes in different modules. This means that we must be able to dynamically determine which modules exist within our package at runtime. This would be straightforward using Python's `pkgutil` module, however, you also state that you are using Nuitka to compile your package into an extension module. `pkgutil` doesn't work with such extension modules.

I cannot find any documented way of determining the modules contained within an Nuitka extension module from within Python. If one does exist, the decorator approach above would work after dynamically importing each submodule.

As it is, I believe the most straightforward solution is to write a script to generate an `__init__.py` before compiling. Suppose we have the following package structure:

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── plugins
│   ├── alpha.py
│   └── beta.py
└── register.py
```

The "plugins" are contained within the `plugins` directory. The contents of the files are:

```
# register.py
# -----------

registry = {}
def register(cls):
    registry[cls.__name__] = cls
    return cls

# __init__.py
# -----------

from . import plugins
from . import register


# ./plugins/alpha.py
# ------------------

from ..register import register

@register
class Alpha(object):
    pass


# ./plugins/beta.py
# ------------------

from ..register import register

@register
class Beta(object):
    pass
```

As it stands, importing the package above will not result in any of the classes being registered. This is because the class definitions are never run, since the modules containing them are never imported. The remedy is to automatically generate an `__init__.py` for the `plugins` folder. Below is a script which does exactly this -- this script can be made part of your compilation process.

```
import pathlib


root = pathlib.Path('./mypkg/plugins')
exclude = {'__init__.py'}

def gen_modules(root):
    for entry in root.iterdir():
        if entry.suffix == '.py' and entry.name not in exclude:
            yield entry.stem

with (root / '__init__.py').open('w') as fh:
    for module in gen_modules(root):
        fh.write('from . import %s\n' % module)
```

Placing this script one directory above your package root (assuming your package is called `mypkg`) and running it yields:

```
from . import alpha
from . import beta
```

Now for the test: we compile the package:

```
nuitka --module mypkg --recurse-to=mypkg
```

and try importing it, checking to see if all of the classes were properly registered:

```
>>> import mypkg
>>> mypkg.register.registry
{'Beta': <class 'mypkg.plugins.beta.Beta'>, 
 'Alpha': <class 'mypkg.plugins.alpha.Alpha'>}
```

Note that the same approach will work with using metaclasses to register the plugin classes, I simply preferred to use decorators here.

Comment: If all the classes are in the same file sure it works, but I want to maintain one class per file.

Comment: @TheGuyWhoCodes so import the decorator class into any files where it is needed....

Comment: @TheGuyWhoCodes I'd suggest adding making that requirement more explicit in your question.

Comment: @BobDylan Importing the decorator in the sub classes which are not imported explicating doesn't work

Comment: This does not work when the `.py` files of the classes that need to be registered are not imported, which is exactly the OP problem.

Comment: @SébastienDeprez I know. My answer came before that requirement was made clear.

Answer (score 0):

If the reflected classes are using your metaclass, you don't need to use `from X import *` to get them registered. Only `import X` should be enough. As soon as the module containing the classes is imported, the classes will be created and available in your metaclass registry.

Comment: @TheGuyWhoCodes Then maybe I misunderstood your problem, or you're doing something else wrong. The simple fact is that you don't need to import each class with `from X import Y` or `from X import *` to get the metaclass to work.

Comment: You do have to explicit import each class for the metaclass to run.

Comment: @TheGuyWhoCodes No, you don't. Importing the module is enough. The class is created when the module is imported. When you explicit import a class you're merely creating a reference in the current  namespace. If you think you need to explicit import each class, you're doing something else wrong.

Comment: I guss there is a misunderstanding of package and module

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with dynamic imports.

**models/regression/base.py**:

```
class Base(object):
    def get_type(self):
        return "BASE"
```

**models/regression/subclass.py**:

```
from models.regression.base import Base

class SubClass(Base):
    def get_type(self):
        return "SUB_CLASS"

__myclass__ = SubClass
```

**loader.py**:

```
from importlib import import_module

class_name = "subclass"
module = import_module("models.regression.%s" % class_name)
model = module.__myclass__()
print(model.get_type())
```

And empty `__init__.py` files in `models/` and `models/regression/`

With:

```
nuitka --recurse-none --recurse-directory models --module loader.py
```

The resulting loader.so contains all the modules under the `models/` subdirectory.